# How to prevent TableView from crashing?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a data model with items. Depending on the situation I only want to show X amount on the tableView. The issue is when I delete items it crashes. I am Using prefix in order to return the amount of items I would like to display like so:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch Section(section) {
    case .image:
        return imageArray.prefix(3).count
    case .subscribe:
        return myArray.count
    }
}
```

I am also getting this error. Please Note: If I did not prefix the ImageArray things work out fine:

> 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Any help would be great as I've been stuck on this for quite sometime.

Thank you

Comment: You are deleting the rows after they made the count of rows, and when looping cannot be found. You need to do this before it loads the view. ViewWillAppear() Also if you delete items while the app is being used. You need to reload the tableview self.tableview.reloadData() so it can have a new row count.

Comment: I don't understand why this works perfect if I have imageArray.count vs what I have above? Nothing crashes and things are being deleted perfectly?

Answer (score 0):

In your cellforrow  you just add guard method below the declaration of cell  guard array.count != 0 else return cell
This will not allow to crash your app.